# CentOS guest eth0 limited to 100Mbps in XenServer host

Tags: centos, linux-networking, xenserver, eth0

The host shows a bond of 2Gbps, but the CentOS guest only has 100Mbps according to dd.  Using ethtool the only information is that the link exists (which I gather is correct for a guest VM).  Xen tools are installed.  Where should I start looking?

Host is Xen Server 6.5.0 and guest is CentOS 6.7 kernel 2.6.32

This is an Ethernet connection to a SAN, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Typically, you use `iperf` to measure network bandwidth. Give this a try and make sure the problem isn't introduced between the network stack and the disk.